# How to instruct Maven to only install test scope dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, karate, cicd

I have a CI involving Karate Tests for smoke testing and I want to speed up this step by installing only the test scope dependencies defined in the pom.xml. Is it possible in Maven?

For example, would that be possible only install test scope dependencies in test goal?

I know I can use docker to prepare a image without installing dependencies every times but I got limitation to use docker.

Comment: See if maven profiles help: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: Alternatively, you could split up your project into multiple Maven modules where one contains the production code and one contains the tests. Another possibility for speeding things up is caching dependencies between builds.

Comment: What do you mean by "installing only the test scope dependencies"?

Comment: @khmarbaise https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope

Comment: Usually maven use cache dependencies to speed up build

Comment: I know all the guides of maven very well. But I'm asking what you mean by `installing only test scope dependencies` (as already asked).. Or are you talking about the downloads happening during the build within container? If so you should mount the local cache into your container to prevent redownloading all the deps...

Comment: @khmarbaise yes. Install test scope deps during build time. Actually could this possible to only install test scope deps for test goal in Maven?